# check to see if elements in one list occurs in another list with recursions

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
firstLst = [1,2,3,4]
secondLst = [5,6,3,2,4,1]
```

If i am passing the two lists above as arguements in a function. I would like to know how I can check if all elements in the firstLst are in the secondLst using recursions with Python. I can achieve this by having two extra parameters i and j which will allow me to check each element in firstLst and secondLst, but is there a way to do this by only having the two lists as parameters?

example of the function with parameters:

```
def firstInSecond(lst1,lst2):
```

How can True be returned if all elements in lst1 are in lst2 otherwise False is returned. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is a straightforward subset check, right?  Look at a tutorial on Python sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't exactly recursive, but simpler.

```
set(firstLst).issubset(set(secondLst))
```

For a recursive answer,

```
def firstInSecond(lst1,lst2):
    if len(lst1) == 0:
       return True
    if lst1[0] in lst2:
       return firstInSecond(lst1[1:], lst2)
    else:
       return False
```